# The WSJT-X package for Ubuntu 22.10 is out date and does not work. How to get the Ubuntu 22.04 package which works

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.10

I have tried the Raspberry PI image for Ubuntu 20.10.  It works well.  But, I use my Raspberry PI 400 to control my WSPR mode radio equipment, which needs the wsjtx software.  I tried to install the repository package for wjstx.  The repository package used is wjstx-2.6.0-rc1.  This is the release candidate for version 2.6.0 and stopped working after November 2022. The installation works, but, software does not.  Is there way of getting the old package version 2.5.4, part of Ubuntu 22.04 installed?  Do I need to change the referenced repository?  Should I try building the wsjtx version 2.6.0 from source under Ubuntu 20.10?  Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Greg KD1XI

Comment: I assume in your question where you typed wjstx you mean wsjtx - I was a little confused looking for the package :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a [known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wsjtx/+bug/2000272) but sadly nobody has had the time or inclination to fix the version in 22.10.

What's probably (arguably) easier is waiting 3 days until the release of Ubuntu 23.04, upgrading to that, and then getting wsjtx from the 23.04 repo, which is version 2.6.1 which likely won't have the same issue as the pre-release in 22.10.

Or you could be super intrepid and upgrade today, 3 days before release and see how it goes ;)

Edit: I'm running 23.04 (prior to release) and have installed wsjtx from the repo, it appears to be working:

[image: wsjtx]

I have no idea how to use this, I assume it's something HAM radio related. I have a Baofeng UV-5RIII which I connected via USB but assume its far too ill equipped (as am I) to operate this :)